# The German Terrorist

Tags: wordplay, language, movies, literature

The CIA has arrested and interrogated a German terror suspect who was trying to enter the country with a Syrian passport. The suspect is low on the totem pole, but he does have information that Daesh will attempt a large terror attack during the Brazil Olympics later this year. However, he does not know what city will be attacked because the mastermind has not shared this information with him. He does have the IP address of the mastermind.

Armed with this information, the CIA sends a National Security Letter to Google, requesting the recent searches made from this IP address. Amongst other things that implicate the other suspects, the mastermind has made a number of searches that ended up on the Wikipedia pages of the following movies and books:

> California
>   Doc Savage
>   The Southerner
>   Every Which Way But Loose
>   The Kentuckian
>   The Baltimore Bullet
>   La Scoumoune
>   Un hombre llamado Noon
>   Lech Wałęsa

Based on this information, the CIA figures out where the attacks will take place. They send a special agent to work together with local authorities and the cell is cleaned up.

What city was the attack planned to take place in?

Comment: @gamow yes, movies and some books. However, I am replacing Amazon with Wikipedia because that might make more sense.

Comment: @Raystafarian what do you mean by that?

Comment: @nate I don't know. That confuses me.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs If I had to guess, I would say Los Lunas, New Mexico.

Comment: More and more, it appears that the FBI is just outsourcing it's investigations to this site.

Comment: @chris yeah, but this way the NSA can recruit as well. win/win

Comment: You're now on a list for this post. And I am now on a list for this comment.

Comment: @SendersReagent everyone over on infosec is already on the list.

Comment: A German with a Syrian passport coming to the US with information on bombing about Brazil...why is the FBI involved? Shouldn't it be CIA? :P

Comment: @stackErr good point. I will edit it. This detail is not important though. I was just confused by all the USA government organisations wit a TLA.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I was half joking but sure :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given the story, it stands to reason that

> The mastermind was visiting the German Wikipedia.

Given that information, here are the Wikipedia pages he probably visited:

> Der Mann aus Virginia
>  Der Mann aus Bronze
>  Der Mann aus dem Süden
>  Der Mann aus San Fernando
>  Der Mann aus Kentucky
>  Der Mann aus Baltimore
>  Der Mann aus Marseille
>  Der Mann aus El Paso
>  Der Mann aus Hoffnung

He hit these pages when searching for this target city,

> Manaus

Comment: You are really close. You've done most of the research, now just put them together.

Comment: You mean the terrorists are going to attack the city of Virginiabronzesudensanfernandokentuckybaltimoremarseilleelpasohoffnung?

Comment: ... Just look up major cities in Brazil and you'll slap yourself for not making the connection.

Comment: Being Brazilian myself, I didn't have to. But I'm slapping myself regardless ;)

Comment: Well, you found it. The idea I originally had was making a poem involving Germans in the city, because Germany has a consulate there, but I'm horrible at making up sensible rhymes. Did you like the puzzle?

Comment: I did, especially the fact that the names of the movies look so different when written in English!